# I can't delete all the record in multiple tables

Tags: database, vb.net, delete-row

Dental table:

```
StudentID
Decayed
```

Visits table:

```
StudentID (This student id can be repeated depends on how many visits they have)
Date
Timein
```

MY SOURCECODE:

```
DELETE a.*, b.* FROM 
Dental a LEFT JOIN Visits b 
ON b.StudentID = a.StudentID 
WHERE a.StudentID = '11111';
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use. MySql is not the same as MS Access.

Comment: Are the fullstops in DELETE a., b. typos?